# Backbone/Underscore. When rendering, 'this.template is not a function' error

Tags: backbone.js, typescript, underscore.js-templating

```
class Crafts extends Backbone.Collection {
  get url() {
    return '../crafts.JSON'
  }
  get model() {
    return Craft
  }
}

class CraftView extends Backbone.View {
  get template() {
    return
   _.template($('#craftTemplate').text());
 }
  render() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    return this.$el;
  }
}

class CraftsView extends Backbone.View {
  render() {
    const self = this;
    this.collection.each((craft) => {
      let view = new CraftView({
        model: craft
      });
      self.$el.append(view.render());
    });
    console.log(this.el)
    return this.$el;
  }
};
```

I get an 'Uncaught TypeError: this.template is not a function' when I try to render. I am modeling my code from an older project that worked, so I am not sure as to why the error is occurring. The only solutions I have come across have been to use bindAll, but I don't think that is the problem here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please don't post images of your code, post it here and use the markup available in the rich text editor tools.

Comment: Sorry, newbie idiocy. Fixed it.

Comment: Why do you have a newline after the `return` in `get template()`? Doesn't that mean that it will always return `undefined`?

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thank you. I'm the king of dumb syntax errors.